# Is it possible to reset the macOS user password via root without old password?

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, password-recovery

I need to change user password on macOS without knowing old password. I tried to use:

```
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/user
```

But got error:

```
Permission denied. Please enter user's old password:
```

Could you please help? Need to find a way to do via terminal for schedule password change process for some cases.

Comment: What is the point of a password if it is easily changed or bypassed?

Comment: @Moab OP is using sudo, so this is the superuser (system administrator) trying to reset a user's password.

Comment: @Yevhen, is the user that you're issuing the command an Admin?